# How to write a shader which can implement the glow effect for a SpriteNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, shader

I've learnt that SpriteKit can support shader. I created a simple shader file with .fsh extension then call the following code

```
            let myShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "testShader.fsh")
            let mySpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mySpriteNode")
            mySpriteNode.shader = myShader
```

Now a need a shader to make my spriteNode glow, the effect would be similar to this one:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dSfDK

Anyone knows how to write the shader?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Can you show code of your best approach at this?

Comment: "How to" questions that are basically looking for a tutorial on a topic generally do not follow the SO format.  You want to ask specific questions that could yield specific answers.  If you think your question could result in possibly many different answers, then you need to fix the question.  I would recommend searching how to do glowing in shaders in general, get an algorithm, attempt to convert the algorithm to swift, then come back asking questions based on what is stopping your algorithm from working correctly.